# How long a thread is alive in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

Is there any way to verify how long a `Thread` is alive?

I want to know how long my `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread` is alive in a ASP.NET page.

Comment: are you looking for timing information or what else are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Just the time(ticks) that thread started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no direct method to achieve that...

BUT you could do this:

- Get the [`ProcessThreadCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthreadcollection.aspx) of the current [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) with [`Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.threads.aspx)
- call [`GetCurrentThreadId`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getcurrentthreadid) (pinvoke since you need the native Thread ID!)
- Iterate over this collection and find the current thread via [ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.id.aspx)
- access the found [`ProcessThread.StartTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.starttime.aspx) to get the Starttime of the current Thread

This gives you [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx)... which you would substract from [`DateTime.Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) to get a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx)... there you can access [`Ticks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.ticks.aspx) etc.

Answer (score 2):

The thread will be alive until the IIS worker thread is recycled, or the server is restarted/turned off. The thread will be reused to handle more requests, so the lifetime of the thread can not be used to determine how long time it takes to handle a request (which I suspect that you really want to find out).

Besides, a single request can be handled by different threads. At certain points in the page life cycle, the execution can be taken over by another thread.

So, how long the thread has been alive is not relevant for the ASP.NET page.